# Android beta testing incorrect permission

Tags: android

My current app has an incorrect permission setting of requiring phone call that prevent tablet from using it. I fixed it in the manifest file and tested it on device. Everything works and I'm trying to do beta testing using Google Play store's beta testing service. I uploaded the new APK and see the feature permissions as

```
android.hardware.LOCATION
android.hardware.location.GPS
android.hardware.location.NETWORK
android.hardware.MICROPHONE
android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN
```

No telephony, good. But when I go to the download link, the old permissions are still there

```
This app has access to these permissions:
...
Your messages
receive text messages (SMS)
...
```

what is going on?? Is this a play store bug?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean or rebuild the project and run application again. It seems AndroidManufest has not been updated

Comment: try to rebuild or clean project and check again